# Fit model with r in SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server

I am trying to follow this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-create-a-predictive-model-r?view=sql-server-2017

The provided code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generate_linear_model;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_linear_model
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'lrmodel <- rxLinMod(formula = distance ~ speed, data = CarsData);
        trained_model <- data.frame(payload = as.raw(serialize(lrmodel, connection=NULL)));'
    , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT [speed], [distance] FROM CarSpeed'
    , @input_data_1_name = N'CarsData'
    , @output_data_1_name = N'trained_model'
    WITH RESULT SETS ((model varbinary(max)));
END;
GO
```

just does not work.

Shouldn't the data be called cars. The cars data also has no column distance but rather dist. I adapted the code like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generate_linear_model;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_linear_model
AS
BEGIN
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
, @script = N'lrmodel <- rxLinMod(formula = distance ~ speed, data = cars);
trained_model <- data.frame(payload = as.raw(serialize(lrmodel, connection=NULL)));'
, @input_data_1 = N'SELECT [speed], [dist] FROM cars'
, @input_data_1_name = N'cars'
, @output_data_1_name = N'trained_model'
WITH RESULT SETS ((model varbinary(max)));
END;
GO
```

but still get errors. Btw I am a bit confused what:

```
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT [speed], [dist] FROM cars'
```

does. Is this a query against the data cars in R? Any pointers would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

PS:

The comment below helped me to fix the code:

```
--CREATE TABLE stopping_distance_models (
--    model_name varchar(30) not null default('default model') primary key,
--    model varbinary(max) not null);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generate_linear_model;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_linear_model
AS
BEGIN
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
,@script = N'data(cars); 
lrmodel <- rxLinMod(formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars);
trained_model <- data.frame(payload = as.raw(serialize(lrmodel, connection=NULL)));'
, @input_data_1 = N''
, @input_data_1_name = N'cars'
, @output_data_1_name = N'trained_model'
WITH RESULT SETS ((model varbinary(max)));
END;
GO

INSERT INTO stopping_distance_models (model)
EXEC generate_linear_model;
```

Comment: You should add `data(cars)` inside `script` and leave empty `@input_data_1`

Comment: Thanks. Please feel free to compose an answer (see PS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should do it is the next, just leave empty `input_data_1` because you are not using any query for your moedel:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
,@script = N'data(cars); 
lrmodel <- rxLinMod(formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars);
trained_model <- data.frame(payload = as.raw(serialize(lrmodel, connection=NULL)));'
, @input_data_1 = N''
, @input_data_1_name = N'cars'
, @output_data_1_name = N'trained_model'
WITH RESULT SETS ((model varbinary(max)));
END;
GO
```

Very useful combining `R` and `SQL`. Let me know any questions about this.